# Python Pandas AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'

Tags: pandas

First question here. I am attempting to use pandas to create a new column ('zone') in my dataframe based on the values of other columns in my dataframe.  I am using address data.

Here is some sample data, my real dataset has 25k rows.
sample_df:

```
Shipping City   Shipping Zip    State   DISTRICT NAME
Garden City 11530   NY  NEW YORK 2
San Francisco   94117   CA  CALIFORNIA 1
Frisco  75036   TX  TEXAS 1
Las Vegas   89139   NV  NV-UT
Beverly Hills   90212   CA  CALIFORNIA 5
```

here is sample criteria for the new column:

In general if in mid west or east coast I can use state to assign the zone.  for NY: zone_8
TX: zone_6
For California, I want to split into 3 different zones: NorCal, Socal, and central Cal -which will also include Las Vegas and Phoenix.  I can use the given 'District Name' column to divide CA only. for special cities I can use 'Shipping City'. he rest of the sample expected results are below:

Expected Result:

```
    Shipping City   | Shipping Zip  | State | DISTRICT NAME | Zone  
-----           | -----         | ----- | -----         | ----- 
Garden City | 11530         | NY    | NEW YORK 2    | zone_8    
San Francisco   | 94117         | CA    | CALIFORNIA 1  | zone_3    
Frisco          | 75036         | TX    | TEXAS 1       | zone_6    
Las Vegas       | 89139         | NV    | NV-UT         | zone_2    
Beverly Hills   | 90212         | CA    | CALIFORNIA 5  | zone_2
```

I created lists for my expected values:

```py
zone8_state = ['ME', 'NH', 'VT', 'MA', 'RI', 'CT', 'AA', 'HI', 'NY', 'PA', 'NJ', 'MD', 'DE',          'WV', 'OH', 'VA', 'NC', 'SC', 'GA', 'FL', 'MI']
zone7_state = ['KY', 'IN', 'IL', 'WI', 'MN', 'TN', 'AL','LA', 'MS', 'AR']
zone6_state = ['IA', 'MO', 'ND', 'SD', 'NE', 'KS', 'OK', 'TX']
zone5_state = ['MT', 'WV', 'CO', 'NM', 'ID', 'WA', 'OR']
zone4_state = ['UT', 'NV', 'AZ']
norcal = ['CALIFORNIA 1', 'CALIFORNIA 2']
socal = ['CALIFORNIA 4', 'CALIFORNIA 5']
zone3_city = ['CALIFORNIA 3', 'Las Vegas', 'Phoenix']
```

Then I made a function:

```py
def get_zones(sample_df):
    if sample_df['State'].isin(zone8_state):
        return 'zone_8'
    elif sample_df['State'].isin(zone7_state):
        return 'zone_7'
    elif sample_df['State'].isin(zone6_state):
        return 'zone_6'
    elif sample_df['State'].isin(zone5_state):
        return 'zone_5'
    elif sample_df['State'].isin(zone4_state) | sample_df['DISTRICT NAME'].isin(norcal):
        return 'zone_4'
    elif sample_df['DISTRICT NAME'].isin(zone3_city) | sample_df['Shipping City'].isin(zone3_city):
        return 'zone_3'
    elif sample_df['DISTRICT NAME'].isin(socal):
        return 'zone_2'
    else:
        return 'check the record'
```

THen I applied the function to my df:

```py
sample_df['zone'] = sample_df.apply(get_zones, axis=1)
```

after I apply though, I get this:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'`

can you please help me to get my function to work correctly?  I also tried using 'contains' instead of 'isin' but also get a similar Attribute error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like this: when you call `.apply` with `axis=1`, the DataFrame gets passed to your `get_zones` function on a row-by-row basis, and the function will operate on each row individually. So within the `get_zones()` function, `sample_df["State"]` (or any other column you index) is a single (`str`) value corresponding to a specific row's entry for that column. Given this, you could modify your function to use Python's built-in `in` keyword,  since you're just doing a simple membership check. In other words, instead of `if sample_df['State'].isin(zone8_state):`, try `if sample_df['State'] in zone8_state:` and so on.

Alternatively, you could abandon `.apply` and restructure `get_zones()` to return a list or array of zones corresponding to the rows of the input DataFrame, then just do `sample_df["zone"] = get_zones(sample_df)`.